# I created a database in spring boot in 1 project now I want to create another project and use that same database in this project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Explanation**
I have a database in which there are 5 tables now I want to create another project and here I want to access the data from these tables. I created this database by using Spring JPA.

So know how I access the data from this database using JPA.

Comment: How do you access db in first project?

Comment: How do you configure JPA?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko through Spring data JPA

Comment: same like giving the db name and it username and password in application properties file

Comment: and then I add data in it by using CrudRepository,

Comment: Why don't you provide same dbname/username/password in application.properties of Project #2?

Comment: yeah but then did I have to write same entity classes again ?

Comment: You can either duplicate your entity and repository classes in second project or move them to separate module (jar) and make both projects dependent on that "Entity" module -- this allows you to reuse classes

Answer (score 0):

Just configure the datasource to point to the existing database.

For details see the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.18.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-data-access.html) on how to configure the datasource.